How to Default a Date Range Slicer in Power BI to Start from the Beginning of the Current Month to Today's Date?
I'm working with a date range slicer in Power BI that is set to "Between" mode to allow users to select both a start and end date. The slicer is connected to my dim_date entity.
I would like the slicer to automatically default to display the date range from the start of the current month up to today's date when users first load the report. However, I still want users to have the ability to manually change the date range if they wish.
Here’s a summary of my setup:

Slicer Type: Date range slicer in "Between" mode

Connected Table: dim_date (with columns like DateKey, Date, Month, etc.)

Default Range: Start of the current month (e.g., 01/12/2024) to today's date (e.g., 18/12/2024)

User Control: Users should still be able to adjust the date range manually.


What I have Tried

Relative Date Slicer: I want users to interact directly with the filters on the report, rather than having to access the filter pane sidebar.

My Goal

Default View: Show start of the current month to today's date.

User Interaction: Allow users to change the range as needed.

Dynamic Update: Ensure the default range updates at the start of each new month.


How can I achieve this behavior for my Power BI date range slicer? Any guidance or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated!

You can't.  But you can add a column to your date table to indicate the days that are part of the current month and filter on that.
